# Given: aabcdddeabb => Expected: [(a,2),(b,1),(c,1),(d,3),(e,1),(a,1),(b,1)] in Scala

Tags: algorithm, scala

I'm really interested in how this algorithm can be implemented. If possible, it would be great to see an implementation with and without recursion. I am new to the language so I would be very grateful for help. All I could come up with was this code and it goes no further:

```
print(counterOccur("aabcdddeabb"))

def counterOccur(string: String) =
string.toCharArray.toList.map(char => {
  if (!char.charValue().equals(char.charValue() + 1)) (char, counter)
  else (char, counter + 1)
})
```

I realize that it's not even close to the truth, I just don't even have a clue what else could be used.

Comment: You don't want a `map` you want a `fold`Left although IMHO it is easier with _(tail)_ recursion. Give it a try.

Comment: In the title I think '...,(b,1)] in Scala' should be '...,(b,2)] in Scala'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First solution with using recursion. I take *Char* by *Char* from string and check if last element in the *Vector* is the same as current. If elements the same I update last element by increasing count(It is first case). If last element does not the same I just add new element to the Vector(second case). When I took all *Chars* from the string I just return result.

```
  def counterOccur(string: String): Vector[(Char, Int)] = {
    @tailrec
    def loop(str: List[Char], result: Vector[(Char, Int)]): Vector[(Char, Int)] = {
      str match {
        case x :: xs if result.lastOption.exists(_._1.equals(x)) =>
          val count = result(result.size - 1)._2
          loop(xs, result.updated(result.size - 1, (x, count + 1)))
        case x :: xs =>
          loop(xs, result :+ (x, 1))
        case Nil => result
      }
    }

    loop(string.toList, Vector.empty[(Char, Int)])
  }

  println(counterOccur("aabcdddeabb"))
```

Second solution that does not use recursion. It works the same, but instead of the recursion it is using foldLeft.

```
  def counterOccur2(string: String): Vector[(Char, Int)] = {
    string.foldLeft(Vector.empty[(Char, Int)])((r, v) => {
      val lastElementIndex = r.size - 1
      if (r.lastOption.exists(lv => lv._1.equals(v))) {
        r.updated(lastElementIndex, (v, r(lastElementIndex)._2 + 1))
      } else {
        r :+ (v, 1)
      }
    })
  }

  println(counterOccur2("aabcdddeabb"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a very simple `foldLeft` to accumulate. You also don't need toCharArray and toList because strings are implicitly convertible to `Seq[Char]`:

```scala
"aabcdddeabb".foldLeft(collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(Char,Int)]()){ (acc, elm) =>
   acc.lastOption match {
     case Some((c, i)) if c == elm => 
       acc.dropRightInPlace(1).addOne((elm, i+1))
     case _ => 
       acc.addOne((elm, 1))
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For

```
str = "aabcdddeabb"
```

you could extract matches of the regular expression

```
rgx = /(.)\1*/
```

to obtain the array

```
["aa", "b", "c", "ddd", "e", "a", "bb"]
```

and then map each element of the array to the desired string.<sup>1</sup>

```
def counterOccur(str: String): List[(Char, Int)] = {
  """(.)\1*""".r
    .findAllIn(str)
    .map(m => (m.charAt(0), m.length)).toList
}
```

```
counterOccur("aabcdddeabb")
  #=> res0: List[(Char, Int)] = List((a,2), (b,1), (c,1), (d,3), (e,1), (a,1), (b,2))
```

The regular expression reads, "match any character and save it to capture group 1 (`(.)`), then match the content of capture group 1 zero or more times (`\1*`).

<sup>1. Scala code kindly provided by @Thefourthbird.</sup>

Comment: @The fourth bird, thank you for your contribution. Whenever I write your username I am vigilant to spell it correctly, as the image of a large yellow bird always comes to mind.

Comment: You are most welcome. Fun fact, did you know Big Bird is blue in the Netherlands? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `foldLeft` and a custom `State` case class:

```scala
def countConsecutives[A](data: List[A]): List[(A, Int)] = {
  final case class State(currentElem: A, currentCount: Int, acc: List[(A, Int)]) {
    def result: List[(A, Int)] =
      ((currentElem -> currentCount) :: acc).reverse
    
    def nextState(newElem: A): State =
      if (newElem == currentElem)
        this.copy(currentCount = this.currentCount + 1)
      else
        State(
          currentElem = newElem,
          currentCount = 1,
          acc = (this.currentElem -> this.currentCount) :: this.acc
        )
  }
  object State {
    def initial(a: A): State =
      State(
        currentElem = a,
        currentCount = 1,
        acc = List.empty
      )
  }
  
  data match {
    case a :: tail =>
      tail.foldLeft(State.initial(a)) {
        case (state, newElem) =>
          state.nextState(newElem)
      }.result
    
    case Nil =>
      List.empty
  }
}
```

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/ZqwHllNOT7KEl3kJlpT3oA/1)*.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use the `unfold` method. This method is defined for several collection types, here I'm using it to produce an `Iterator` (documented [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.8/scala/collection/Iterator$.html#unfold%5BA,S%5D(init:S)(f:S=%3EOption%5B(A,S)%5D):Iterator%5BA%5D) for version 2.13.8):

```
def spans[A](as: Seq[A]): Iterator[Seq[A]] =
  Iterator.unfold(as) {
    case head +: tail =>
      val (span, rest) = tail.span(_ == head)
      Some((head +: span, rest))
    case _ =>
      None
  }
```

`unfold` starts from a state and applies a function that returns, either:

- `None` if we want to signal that the collection ended
- `Some` of a pair that contains the next item of the collection we want to produce and the "remaining" state that will be fed to the next iteration.

In this example in particular, we start from a sequence of `A` called `as` (which can be a sequence of characters) and at each iteration:

- if there's at least one item

  - we split head and tail
  - we further split the tail into the longest prefix that contains items equal to the head and the rest
  - we return the head and the prefix we got above as the next item
  - we return the rest of the collection as the state for the following iteration
- otherwise, we return `None` as there's nothing more to be done

The result is a fairly flexible function that can be used to group together spans of equal items. You can then define the function you wanted initially in terms of this:

```
def spanLengths[A](as: Seq[A]): Iterator[(A, Int)] =
  spans(as).map(a => a.head -> a.length)
```

This can be probably made more generic and its performance improved, but I hope this can be an helpful example about another possible approach. While folding a collection is a recursive approach, unfolding is referred to as a *corecursive* one ([Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corecursion)).

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/a8152ujUSzaPRS4tthHKrQ/14).